# Getting McAfee warnings despite not having McAfee?

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I own a Galaxy S10, and after the recent update I've started getting warnings from McAfee in my Chrome browser telling me sites I've been visiting for years are suspicious... except I don't have and have never had McAfee installed on my phone or browser. I've searched my apps and turned up empty-handed, and searching online hasn't helped either, so any idea what this is?

Comment: Do you think the warning is displayed by an app or can the warning be caused by the web-site itself (e.g. a dialog created by JavaScript in the HTML page may be from an ad shown on the page)?

Comment: If possible, could you take the screenshot when it happens and upload it here? Currently, I believe it's kind of the usual [scareware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scareware) to make you "download/buy" (fake) antivirus app.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it appears to be the digital secure app. I'm not sure why it says McAfee in the browser.

Comment: Is this Verizon's Digital Secure? Looks like [Verizon is working together with McAfee](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20190106005048/en/McAfee-and-Verizon-Team-up-to-Secure-Connected-Devices-in-the-Home).